# Error from Yammer feed embed: Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression

Tags: yammer

I recently embedded a feed on one of our SharePoint pages. The feed worked fine 2 days ago but today i get the following error:

Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /^[^Ö-×¿Ø€-Û¿Ý-Ý¿à¢ -à£¿ï¬-ï­ï­-ï·¿ï¹°-﻿]*[A-Za-zÃ€-Ã–Ã˜-Ã¶Ã¸-Ê¸Ì€-Öà €-á¿¿â°€-ï¬œï¸€-ï¹¯ï»½-ï¿¿]/: Range out of order in character class

The error seems to occur at:
https://s0.assets-yammer.com/assets/yam-platform-feed-9bcb8d2f0391f8bdbf6bb270b9167e88.js line 57

Additional information:

- This error only happen with this specific Yammer group
- The error doesn't occur in other groups i tested it with
- The Yammer Embed script is as is provided by Yammer (the network and group-id are changed)
- Tested in both IE10/11 and Chrome 49.0.2623.112

[Screenshot from Chrome Developer Tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZKAs.png)

Can anyone with help with this problem?

Comment: Is this problem still occurring for you? In future, please also include your initialization code for Embed. Service issues are best reported through a support case to Microsoft.